# How to make My UIControl subclass as superclass of programmatically created UIElements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uielement, uicontrol

In my application I want to associate `NSMutableDictionary` to all `UIElements` (`UIButton`, `UILable`, etc), I can easily achieve this by subclassing each element, but I just want to know if I can make my own `UIControl` subclass -with a property of type `NSMutableDictionary`-, as superclass of all programmatically created `UIElement` s in anyway, so that I can reduce the number of subclasses.

Here like this

```
@interface UIControl : MyControls
{

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *details;
@end
```

and make `MyControls` as superclass of all programmatically created UIElements

Comment: What do you mean by associate NSMutableDictionary to all UIElements? Are you saying add an NSMutableDictionary as a property to every UIElement?  So you want a UIButton to have a dictionary attached to it?  What is your goal? There is probably a much better way to solve whatever problem you are dealing with.

Comment: @Inturbidus You can give that solution as answer and i'll change my question accordingly

Comment: Well that doesn't answer your question.  I can probably help solve the problem, but I need to know what your goal is?

Comment: @Inturbidus I create UIElements dynamically according to an XML, so whenever user interact with those UIElements I want to update the dictionary associated with that element

Comment: Well it probably makes more sense to keep your XML in an array with IDs and set the tag of each UIButton and UILabel to the id of the XML element and update it accordingly. Subclassing is a useful technique for somethings but using the control to store data is a bad idea for many reasons including memory and accessing the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, not by subclassing, but by adding your own properties and methods to `UIControl` itself (the superclass of `UIButton`, `UILabel`, etc.). These will then be inherited by any standard buttons, labels, etc. that you instantiate. Objective-C lets you add your own methods very easily using [Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1). However, you can't add instance variables via categories. To do that, you need to use Associative References which are documented in the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

There's a good tutorial on how to do this [here](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html).

By the way, I don't necessarily disagree with inturbidus. But if you're sure you want to go this route, that's how you'd do it.

Comment: Categories != Subclasses.  Be careful doing this.

Comment: @CodaFi Edited the answer to clarify that it's not subclassing.

Comment: Doesn't change my earlier point, though thank you for the clarification.  Categories are still inherently... Dangerous (as in not completely safe) when it comes to associated objects.